# Converting string to date object not working properly

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array of object like this:

```
const days = [
{
    _id: 12312323
    date : '30/12/2021'
    dateStatus : 'presence'
},
...
]
```

and I want to convert the date property from string to date object this way:

```js
const convertToDateObject = (dateString: string): Date => {
    const dateParts: any[] = dateString.split("/");
    return new Date(+dateParts[2], dateParts[1] - 1, +dateParts[0]);
};

for (let i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
    const d = days[i].date as string;
    days[i].date = convertToDateObject(d);
}
```

But this returns this converts the date value to this format `'Wed Dec 01 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)'` instead of this format `2021-11-30T23:00:00.000Z`**.

I am actually lost because when the given object does not have the `_id` property the formatting is working properly and it returns the wanted format, but when it does have the `_id` property then it returns me another format. Why?

Comment: If you're looking at the date in the console you will see the Date object\string as this: `Wed Dec 01 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)`. But if you need its ISO representation in UTC, then use the following: `new Date().toISOString()`

Comment: @Max if I console.log the returned value from ```convertToDateObject(d)``` then it is good format, but the problem is happening when i am affecting this value to ```days[i].date = ...```

Answer (score 4):

> But this returns this converts the date value to this format...

No, it doesn't. It gives you a [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object, which has no "format." You can get the date/time information from that object either in local time (apparently GMT+0100 where you are), or in UTC, depending on what methods you use. To get information from the object in local time, you use `getHours`, `getMinutes`, `getSeconds` (etc.), `toString`, `toLocaleString`, and similar. To get information from the object in UTC, you use `getUTCHours`, `getUTCMinutes`, `getUTCSeconds` (etc.), `toUTCString`, and similar.

The constructor you're using **does** work in local time. That is, it constructs a `Date` object for midnight (because you're not providing hours, minutes, seconds, or milliseconds) local time in your timezone (because you've used `new Date`). If you want to get midnight UTC, you can do `new Date(Date.UTC(+dateParts[2], dateParts[1] - 1, +dateParts[0]));` instead. The only difference is the moment in time that the `Date` object represents (the given date at midnight local time vs. the given date at midnight UTC).

Comment: Thank you for your answer bu still not getting what is happening, I  don't think my question was clear.
Actually the returned value from ```convertToDateObject(d)``` is working properly and it returns this format ```2021-11-30T23:00:00.000Z``` but the problem is happening when i am putting this value in ```days[i].date``` it is being converted to a string ```'2021-11-30T23:00:00.000Z'```.
the *buggy* thing is when i delete the _id property from the object then everything works fine but it is not a good solution.

Comment: @SirageDb Where do see this incorrect format of the Date? Because there's a big chance, you have a local Date object in that variable, but the way this Date is displayed "seems" like it's a string.

Comment: @Max I have no idea why the returned value from `convertToDateObject(d)` is isoString but getting stored in `days[i].date` as a string. I found two solutions to the problem :

1. reconstructing each object `day` in the array days without the `_id` `javascript days[i]={date : convertToDateObject(d), dateStatus: days[i].dateStatus}` 

2.  keeping the `_id` and replacing the date using a spread operator like this (which is the solution i ended up with) : `javascript days[i] = {...days[i], date : convertToDateObject(d)}`

Comment: @SirageDb - *"I have no idea why the returned value from convertToDateObject(d) is isoString..."* It isn't, with the function you've shown in your question. Again: It's a `Date` object.